# Unable to extract td having different classes using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The below mentioned html is a single 'tr' block from a table.
My objective is to extract each value from the 'tr' block.

**HTML:**

```
   <tr><th colspan="7" class="tablehead">
Historical Data for NIFTY 50
</th></tr>
<tr><th colspan="7" class="tablehead">
For the period 01-01-2019 to 10-01-2019
</th></tr>
      <tr>          
           <th >Date</th>
           <th >Open</th>
           <th >High</th>
           <th >Low</th>
           <th >Close</th>
           <th>Shares Traded</th>
           <th >Turnover <br/>(<!--Rs.--> <img src="/images/rup_t1.gif" 
                alt = "Rs." border="0"> Cr)</th>
     </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td class="date"><nobr>01-Jan-2019</nobr></td>
                  <td class="number">    10881.70</td>
                  <td class="number">    10923.60</td>
                  <td class="number">    10807.10</td>
                  <td class="number">    10910.10</td>
                  <td class="number">      159404542</td>
                   <td class="number">         8688.26</td> 
                  </tr>
```

**Python code:**

```py
rows=soup.find_all("tr")
for row in rows:
    cells=row.find_all('td')
    print(cells)
```

**Output:**

```
[]
```

**Desired output:**

```
[01-Jan-2019,10881.70,10923.60,10807.10,10910.10,159404542,8688.26]
```

Comment: were you able to solve this using one of the answers posted below? If yes, you may marks one! cheers

Comment: No, I am not able to solve the specific purpose. This solution that you have provided picks up any text that is within the td tag. I need to pick up values only with class="number" and class="date"

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

test = '''<tr> <td class="date"><nobr>01-Jan-2019</nobr></td> 
<td class="number">10881.70</td> 
<td class="number">10923.60</td> 
<td class="number">10807.10</td> 
<td class="number">10910.10</td> 
<td class="number">159404542</td> 
<td class="number">8688.26</td> 
</tr>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(test, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all("tr")


for d in data:
      print([d.text.strip().replace("\n", ",").rstrip()])
```

OUTPUT:

```
['01-Jan-2019,10881.70,10923.60,10807.10,10910.10,159404542,8688.26']
```

**EDIT:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

test = '''<tr> <td class="date"><nobr>01-Jan-2019</nobr></td> 
<td class="number">10881.70</td> 
<td class="number">10923.60</td> 
<td class="number">10807.10</td> 
<td class="number">10910.10</td> 
<td class="number">159404542</td> 
<td class="number">8688.26</td> 
</tr>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(test, 'html.parser')
number = soup.find("nobr")
data = soup.find_all("td", class_ ="number")
data_list = []
for n in number:
    data_list.append(n)
    for d in data:
        data_list.append(d.text)

print(data_list)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['01-Jan-2019', '10881.70', '10923.60', '10807.10', '10910.10', '159404542', '8688.26']
```

Comment: can it be done using 'td' tag? Because, there are 'th' tags too which I need to omit.

Comment: Also, i need to specific to pick up values only from these two classes and not any other class.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use css Or syntax to specify multiple selectors

```
soup.select("nobr, td.number")
```

That is

```
data = [item.text for item in soup.select("nobr, td.number")]
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.
Having a function defined which checks if both the classes exists, can solve the issue.

```
def class_variants(css_class):
        list=['date','number']
        return css_class in list

rows = soup.find_all("tr")
for row in rows:
        cells=row.find_all('td', class_=class_variants)
        print(str(cells))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after but I took your html, and in the Turnover `<th>` inserted another date `<td>`  (just so we have two of those, to see if both can be captured) and also another `<td>` with a dummy class to see if it can be excluded. Now it looks like this:

```
html ='''
<tr><th colspan="7" class="tablehead">
Historical Data for NIFTY 50
</th></tr>
<tr><th colspan="7" class="tablehead">
For the period 01-01-2019 to 10-01-2019
</th></tr>
      <tr>          
           <th >Date</th>
           <th >Open</th>
           <th >High</th>
           <th >Low</th>
           <th >Close</th>
           <th>Shares Traded</th>
           <th >Turnover <br/>(<!--Rs.--> <img src="/images/rup_t1.gif" 
                alt = "Rs." border="0"> Cr)</th>
     </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td class="date"><nobr>01-Jan-2019</nobr></td>
                  <td class="number">    10881.70</td>
                  <td class="number">    10923.60</td>
                  <td class="date"><nobr>08-Jan-2017</nobr></td>
                  <td class="number">    10807.10</td>
                  <td class="number">    10910.10</td>
                  <td class="sushi">    zumba</td>
                  <td class="number">      159404542</td>
                  <td class="number">         8688.26</td> 
                  </tr>
'''
```

The code:

```
info = soup.findAll('td', {'class':['date', 'number']})
```

or

```
info = [item.text for item in soup.select(".date, .number")]
```

then:

```
for i in info:
   print(i.strip())
```

Output:

```
01-Jan-2019
10881.70
10923.60
08-Jan-2017
10807.10
10910.10
159404542
8688.26
```